# how to enable button when user enter correct email or 10 digit mobile number?

Tags: javascript, angular

how to enable a button when user enter correct email or 10 digits mobile number?

here is my code
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p5knn6?file=src%2Findex.html

```
<div class="login_div">
  <form action="">
    <input type="text" name="email"
           autocomplete ="off"
           placeholder="Enter the Email or Number"
           [(ngModel)]="userenterValue"
           required
           pattern="^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$">
    <input type="submit" value="Continue" class="btn disbled" disabled="disabled">
  </form>
</div>
```

I added the `pattern` which check only `email`.But user can enter 10 digit number also

can we add this pattern also?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an or statement to your pattern: ("|" pipe symbol)

^\w+([.-]?\w+)*@\w+([.-]?\w+)*(.\w{2,3})+|\d{1,10}$

This will match if either side of the pipe is true

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`bitwise or (|)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#.7c_%28Bitwise_OR%29) operator to combine multiple set of patterns.

Try the following:

`pattern="(\d{10})|(^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$)"/>`

**Working Code Example:**

```js
var input = document.querySelector('[name=email]');
var patt = new RegExp(input.getAttribute('pattern'));
input.oninput = function(event) {
  if(patt.test(this.value)){
    document.querySelector('#btnSubmit').disabled = false;
  }
  else{
    document.querySelector('#btnSubmit').disabled = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="login_div">
  <form action="">
    <input type="text" name="email"
       autocomplete ="off"
       placeholder="Enter the Email or Number"
       [(ngModel)]="userenterValue"
       required
       pattern="(\d{10})|(^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$)"/>
    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Continue" class="btn disbled" disabled="disabled">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: but 10 digit only when user try to add number

Comment: but if user try to enter `email` it can be any number not limited

Comment: it is not correct `anwser`  in this user input field user will enter `email` or phone number if user try to `phone  number` it only `10` digit